# Issue with converting byte encoded data back to int32 after UDP transmission

Tags: java, c#, networking, byte, datagram

I'm assembling Datagrams for UDP communications with a subheader that I use to indicate the type of data being sent. The Client is running C#, the Server is running Java, and the subheader is a single Int32 so 4 bytes of data.

The data successfully arrives at the Server and the subheader + data are correctly interpreted, but when I send a response back to the Client, using BitConverter.ToInt32(subheader, 0) results in an 8 digit number which doesn't map to any of my expected integers. The data sent, however, is correctly displayed by skipping the subheader, which makes me think the problem is exclusive to the subheader encoding/decoding process.

I have methods at both ends that can scrub the subheader from the byte array, and that try to map the scrubbed subheader to a MsgType. Like I mentioned, everything works as expected on the Server, so I suspect the problem lies with encoding at the Server or decoding back at the Client.

I've also tried using a MemoryStream and BinaryReader to convert to Int32, but with the same results.

C# Client:

```
        const SUBHEADER_SIZE = 4; // 4 bytes to an Int32

        private void ReceiveUdp(IAsyncResult packet)
        {
            IPEndPoint remote = (IPEndPoint)Udp.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
            byte[] received = Udp.EndReceive(packet, ref remote);
            MsgType type = GetMsgType(received);
            string msg;

            switch (type)
            {
                case MsgType.POS:
                case MsgType.STATE:
                case MsgType.STATUS:
                    msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ScrubSubheader(received));
                    if (msg.Equals("0"))
                        Disconnect();
                    break;
                case MsgType.MSG:   // Default to MSG
                default:
                    msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ScrubSubheader(received));
                    LocalConsole.Instance.Log("Received [" + type + "] " + msg + " from " + remote.Address + " on port " + remote.Port);
                    break;
            }
        }

        public static byte[] ScrubSubheader(byte[] arr)
        {
            byte[] scrubbed = new byte[arr.Length - SUBHEADER_SIZE];
            for (int i = 0; i < scrubbed.Length; i++)
                scrubbed[i] = arr[i + SUBHEADER_SIZE];
            return scrubbed;
        }

        public static MsgType GetMsgType(byte[] arr)
        {
            byte[] subheader = new byte[SUBHEADER_SIZE];

            for (int i = 0; i < SUBHEADER_SIZE; i++)
                subheader[i] = arr[i];

            int iType = BitConverter.ToInt32(subheader, 0);
            MsgType mtType;

            // Also tried: "MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(subheader); 
            // int iType = new BinaryReader(stream).ReadInt32();"

            LocalConsole.Instance.Log("iType is " + iType, true);

            switch(iType)
            {
                case (int)MsgType.POS:
                    mtType = MsgType.POS;
                    break;
                case (int)MsgType.STATE:
                    mtType = MsgType.STATE;
                    break;
                case (int)MsgType.STATUS:
                    mtType = MsgType.STATUS;
                    break;
                case (int)MsgType.MSG:  // Default to MSG
                default:
                    mtType = MsgType.MSG;
                    break;
            }

            return mtType;
        }
```

Java Server:

```
    public void run() {
        try (DatagramSocket udpServSock = new DatagramSocket(_port)) {

            DatagramPacket packet = null;
            byte[] byteArr = new byte[HubrisServer.MAX_PACKET_SIZE];

            while (true) {

                packet = new DatagramPacket(byteArr, byteArr.length);
                udpServSock.receive(packet);

                InetAddress clientAdd = packet.getAddress();
                int clientPort = packet.getPort();

                MsgType type = getMsgType(packet.getData());
                String msg = DataToString(scrubSubheader(packet.getData()), true);

                MsgType sendType = HubrisServer.MsgType.STATUS;

                msg = "0";
                byte[] sendArr = assemblePacket(msg.getBytes(), sendType);

                DatagramPacket sendPack = new DatagramPacket(sendArr, sendArr.length, clientAdd, clientPort);

                Thread.sleep(1000);

                udpServSock.send(sendPack);
            }
        } catch ... {
            ...
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assemble a packet with subheader and data
     * @param arr
     * @param type
     * @return packet
     */
    public static byte[] assemblePacket(byte[] arr, MsgType type) {
        ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
        buff.putInt(type.getValue());
        byte[] subheader = buff.array();
        byte[] packet = new byte[arr.length + subheader.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < packet.length; i++) {
            if(i >= subheader.length)
                packet[i] = arr[i - subheader.length];
            else
                packet[i] = subheader[i];
        }

        return packet;
    }

    /**
     * Scrub the subheader from a byte array and return the scrubbed array
     * @param arr
     * @return
     */
    public static byte[] scrubSubheader(byte[] arr)
    {
        ... similar to C# implementation
    }

    public static MsgType getMsgType(byte[] arr)
    {
        byte[] subArr = new byte[SUBHEADER_SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < SUBHEADER_SIZE; i++)
            subArr[i] = arr[i];

        ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(subArr);
        int iType = buff.getInt();
        MsgType mtType;

        if(iType == MsgType.POS.getValue())
            mtType = MsgType.POS;
        else if (iType == MsgType.STATE.getValue())
            mtType = MsgType.STATE;
        else if (iType == MsgType.STATUS.getValue())
            mtType = MsgType.STATUS;
        else // Default to MSG
            mtType = MsgType.MSG;

        return mtType;
    }
```

Comment: What are the bytes you are getting, what do you expect, what do you get when converting them

Comment: Is one of those machines Windows and the other one Linux? Could be a byte order issue (Windows is LittleEndian). Try reversing the byte order of those first 4 bytes before convering it to int32. See if that number looks more familiar. Easiest to copy those into separate little buffer and do Array.Reverse.

Comment: In the C# GetMsgType() method, after calling BitConverter.ToInt32(subheader, 0), iType is 16777216. In the Java assemblePacket(byte[] arr, MsgType type) method, buff.putInt(type.getValue()) is being passed a value of 1.

Both sides are running on a Windows machine. I'll try poking around with LittleEndian and see.

Comment: It seems that in C# AssemblePacket(byte[] arr, MsgType type), "byte[] subheader = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)type);" is resulting in an array with length 4, and values "2000". When the packet is received back, the subheader contents (with an input of 1) are a length 4 array containing "0001". Based on my limited knowledge of endianness, am I correct in thinking that the returned subheader is little-endian (1 value in the furthest right byte)? It also appears that the BitConverter.GetBytes((int)type) call is returning just the integer 2 in the 0 index of the array, so I'll look into that too.

Comment: 16777216 = 0x01000000, so it does indeed look like an endian issue.

Comment: It was an endian issue. It seems ByteBuffers in Java default to big endian, so switching them over with ".order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)" solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Avo Nappo and VGR, it was determined to be an endian issue. (If either of you submit your comment as an answer I'll accept it as the answer)

It seems ByteBuffers in Java default to big endian, so switching them over with ".order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)" solved the problem.